# On Click slide div left or right using jquery plus css

Tags: jquery, html, css, sliding

On the 2 following images, im trying to describe what i want to accomplish on my jQuery sliding

[image: there are multiple product boxes in my website]

[image: i need a popup next to particular clicked product and other product box should be moved to next line]

**IMAGE 01 :** there are multiple product boxes in my website

**IMAGE 02 :** i need a popup next to particular clicked product and other product box should be moved to next line

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: i have just started, the designing part and as new bee to JQUERY.. i haven't done any coding for this...

Comment: can anyone let me know what can be done or any such demo?

Comment: We're to fix/help you with your existing code that you have tried. Not do it all for you.

Comment: **Some hint:**  give fixed width to main div. inside that product 01 to 06  div`inline-block`. Description div open in  main div with `display:inline-block`.

Comment: ok Downmenfart.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by hiding the descriptions and showing them using jQuery.
The issue is: if you want desc divs to push product divs, it's going to be weird when you click on products of the last column.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/tzg3rswv/

```
/* jQuery */

$(function() {
    $('.product').click(function() {
        $('.desc').hide();
        $(this).next().css('display', 'inline-block');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you are asking but this might help. The code and syntax for most JQuery animation is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('element').animate(properties);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/
Or here would be an actual example: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaHurlburt/avttkdst/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I won't do all for you, but here is [a well started point](http://jsfiddle.net/f0yvgtjt/):

```
var products = $(".products");
var info = $(".info", products), pos;
var lastClick;

var some_info = [6,
    "Product 1 <br/>  Info AAAAAAAAA",
    "Product 2 <br/>  Info BBBBBBBBB",
    "Product 3 <br/>  Info CCCCCCCCC",
    "Product 4 <br/>  Info DDDDDDDDD",
    "Product 5 <br/>  Info EEEEEEEEE",
    "Product 6 <br/>  Info FFFFFFFFF"
];

$("[data-id]", products).each(function(){
    var o = $(this);
    o.html("Product " + o.data("id"));
    o.on("click", function(){
        pos = info.detach();
        o.after(pos);
        info.fadeIn().animate({
            "top": o.offset().top + 20,
            "left": o.offset().left + o.innerWidth()
        });
        if (lastClick == o) {
            info.hide();
        }
        lastClick = o;
        info.html(some_info[o.data("id")]);
    });
});
```

Nice coding =) ... and any doubts [check jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/) or ask a more detailed question here.